# How to count all the lines of files

Tags: linux, macos

I also need the directory name to be outputs as well. What I was able to do is to output the total number of lines in all directories with directory name.

```
find . -name '*.c' | xargs wc -l | xargs -I{} dirname {} | xargs -I{} dirname {}
```

Comment: Can you re-iterate your requirements with a proper example? Can you explain it more with details?

Comment: @Inian,  basically I want to have  the directory path and the number of lines ending with a semicolon in that directory (number of lines from all files in that directory). I can output the total number of lines ending with a semicolon in the directory with ' find  . -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 grep '[;]$' | wc -l '  but I have no idea how to get the output by directory.

Comment: @Inian, did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have jumbled up a mixture of `bash` commands mostly `GNU`-specific, make sure you have them, `GNU grep` and `GNU Awk`

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -c ';$' | \
  awk -F":" '$NF>0{cmd="dirname "$1; while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {printf "%s\t%s\n",result,$2} close(cmd) }'
```

The idea is `grep -c` returns the pattern count in format, `file-name:count`, which I am passing it to `GNU Awk` to filter those files whose count is greater than zero and print the directory of the file containing it and the count itself.

As a fancy one-liner as they call it these days,

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -c ';$' | awk -F":" '$NF>0{cmd="dirname "$1; while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {printf "%s\t%s\n",result,$2} close(cmd) }'
```

Comment: Does the job!  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for dir in */; do (
    cd "$dir"
    count=$(find . -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 grep '[;]$' | wc -l)
    echo -e "${count}\t${dir}"
) done
```

If you want numbers for each sub-directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for dir in $(find . -type d); do (
    cd "$dir"
    count=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.c' -print0 | \
        xargs -0 grep '[;]$' | wc -l)
    echo -e "${count}\t${dir}"
) done
```

Using `-maxdepth 1` makes sure the calculation is only done in the current directory, not its sub-directories. So each file is counted once.

Comment: is there a way to modify the loop to look in the subdirectories also?

Comment: Added another script.